# Can I make my div inherit height and position from one div and width from another?

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-4, styling

I have a div (div1) inside some other divs. Now I want this div to have the same width as the body (take up full width of display), but always have the same height and position as its parent (div2). I've tried using position: absolute; on this div (div1). Then I can either

- set body to position: relative; and have div1 take up 100% width, but now I'm having trouble making the height always follow div2.
- or set the parent (div2) to position: relative; and have div 1 take up 100% height, but now I can't make it follow the width of body.

It would be cool if CSS had the option of saying:

```
.div1 {
height: 100%(.div2); 
width: 100%(body); 
position: 0(.div2); 
}
```

Or something like that

JSFiddle with the relevant bits: https://jsfiddle.net/Hamleyburger/fqe5o46c/1/#&togetherjs=K02DaSO2nR

- What I want is the div ".selectable" to have a div (inside?) that shows on hover and fits the heights of ".selectable" (parent) and the entire width of the body.

Extra, maybe relevant info:
I'm using Bootstrap and (Jinja2) templating. All the divs so far are taking their base widths from a wrapper container (.main) in my base template that I've set to be (responsively) narrower than body. If I were to remove .main 
div I would have to set width on many individual divs. That would solve it (I could make all the divs that aren't div1 narrower), but it wouldn't be very DRY. I'm using SASS, if that helps.

Comment: Can you post  your code or a working snippet?

Comment: Hey! Sorry for the late response. I have never used jsfiddle before, but I thought that would be a good way to share so I've tried making something here and removing most of the irrelevant stuff: https://jsfiddle.net/Hamleyburger/fqe5o46c/1/#&togetherjs=K02DaSO2nR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to force a div to fill the whole viewport width using `vw`. It's a bit weird though:

```css
body,
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.outer {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative
}

.inner {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

I'd recommend to make your `outer` div full width and give the `inner` one a specific width:

```css
body,
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.outer {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    position: relative
}

.inner {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried copying the contents of your body, .outer and .inner into my body, .selectable and .div1 (where div1 is the child of selectable) - from the example where you use the vw. But in my code div1 is not getting any wider. Is what you're suggesting in the second example that I should not have any element above (any parent, grand parent etc..) which has a lower width? I currently have body > main (which has max width 700px) > product-container (for containing a list of products) > selectable (which is a selectable product and has the height I want the div1 to have)

Comment: @Alma, thanks for adding the jsfiddle. I've created one with the solution using `vw`: https://jsfiddle.net/s1c0yhau/
This solution is fine, but personally I prefer the second one where you would not add a `max-width` to `.main` but to `.row` instead. You'd probably have to change some more parts of your CSS to make the second solution work. But this is just personal preference I think.

Comment: Thanks so much man! Much appreciated. Maybe I'm obsessing too much about the DRY thing. Gonna try out your solution now.

Comment: You‘re welcome @Alma. if you consider your question as answered, feel free to accept it ;)

Comment: @Alma, I'll take a look at it. Could you please send an updated jsfiddle?

Comment: sorry, I deleted the question as soon as I realized it was a bad question. Just in case - I wondered why the background colour wasn't taking up full width even though I could see in Dev Tools that the outline of the div took the entire width of body. It turned out I had set overflow-x: auto; in an ancestor (main), so instead of showing the div was made sideways scrollable.